# Remove non letters / numbers from database

Tags: mysql

I used Dragon Naturally Speaking to process a bunch of audio and the results got imported to a database. Now I have a bunch of crazy characters in the database like: `ï¿½`. How can I get rid of all the symbols / other stuff that isn't a "normal" space or letter / number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DELETE FROM tbl WHERE results NOT REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]+'` -- a tweak from the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

### UPDATE

As I'd misunderstood what @Alan was asking...
My first inclination would be to strip out the noise using external code. If you can't do that, [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/) has [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-documentation/functions-and-operators/string-functions/regular-expressions-functions/regexp_replace/) out of the box, for mysql proper, there [exists a UDF](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp) that does similar. So, you use something like:

```
UPDATE tbl SET results = regexp_replace(results, '[^[:alnum:][:space:]]' '');
```

You could use the function from [this page](http://www.nacodes.com/2013/01/29/Create-Function-MySQL-Regex-replace-TRIM-for-MySQL):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION  `regex_replace`(pattern VARCHAR(1000),replacement VARCHAR(1000),original VARCHAR(1000))

RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000);
 DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1);
 DECLARE i INT;
 DECLARE j INT;
 DECLARE qbTemp VARCHAR(1000);

 SET i = 1;
 SET j = 1;
 SET temp = '';
 SET qbTemp = '';

 IF original REGEXP pattern THEN
  loop_label: LOOP
   IF i>CHAR_LENGTH(original) THEN
    LEAVE loop_label; 
   END IF;
   SET ch = SUBSTRING(original,i,1);
   IF NOT ch REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,ch);
   ELSE
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,replacement);
   END IF;
   SET i=i+1;
  END LOOP;
 ELSE
  SET temp = original;
 END IF;
 SET temp = TRIM(BOTH replacement FROM temp);
 SET temp = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(temp , CONCAT(replacement,replacement),CONCAT(replacement,'#')),CONCAT('#',replacement),''),'#','');
 RETURN temp;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then I was able to run this command:

UPDATE transcripts SET transcript = regex_replace('[^[:alnum:][:space:]]','', transcript);``

Hope that helps...

Comment: and that will remove just the non "alnum" and not the entire record?

Comment: I am using regular old mysql and when I try runnin `make` on the UDF I get this error: `error your installation does not support loading UDFs`, This is on a live server, is there a different command that doesn't need to recompile mysql.

Comment: regexp_replace is only built-in to mariadb, which you aren't using. and you'll need to load the UDF in order to use it on vanilla mysql.

Comment: Do what you wish, Alan

Comment: Thanks, one minor edit which I forgot is the new function is regex_replace, but the SQL query puts it as regexp_replace. Something minor, just mentioning it.

Comment: Final command was `UPDATE transcripts SET transcript = regex_replace('[^[:alnum:][:space:][:punct:]]', '', transcript);`
 Just a warning, the function above will trim anything over 1000 chars.